# Irreducible factors of $x^q-1$ over $\mathbb{Z}_p$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, factoring, irreducible-polynomials, minimal-polynomials

The polynomial $x^3-1$ over $\mathbb{Z}_p$, where $p$ is a prime, factors as $(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$.

The polynomial $x^7-1$ over $\mathbb{Z}_{13}$ factors as, $(x-1)(x^2+3x+1)(x^2+5x+1)(x^2+6x+1)$.

All these $(x-1),(x^2+x+1),(x^2+3x+1),(x^2+5x+1),(x^2+6x+1)$ are irreducible factors.

Does a polynomial $x^q-1$ over $\mathbb{Z}_p$, where $p,q$ are primes ($q<p$), always factorize to $(x-1)$ times several quadratic factors of the form $(x^2+ax+1)$, where $a \in \mathbb{Z}_p$? (a quadratic factor with constant term "1"?)

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I have answered this question and its generalizations in various guises, and have tried to link them together. Here is one such [cluster](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/153429?sort=active) following those links covers the theme pretty much, I think.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JyrkiLahtonen with the newly added details in the comnents to the question, is there a place where you have got that the quadratic polynomial should be of the form $x^2+mx+1$, where $m\in \mathbb{Z}_p$?

Comment: Thomas, sorry about missing that extra question. If $x^2+mx+1$ is irreducible over $\Bbb{Z}_p$, then its zeros are $\alpha$ and $\alpha^p$ (by Galois theory). By Vieta relations the product of the zeros is $+1=\alpha^{p+1}$ meaning that the order of $\alpha$ as a root of unity is a factor of $p+1$. You see this well in your latter example as $7\mid (13+1)$.

Comment: There is a slip in your handling of $x^3-1$. The factor $x^2+x+1$ is not always irreducible. For example if $p=7$ we have $(x-2)(x-4)\equiv x^2+x+1\pmod7$.  However, by that general observation in my previous comment when $3\mid p+1$ we can (and actually do!) get an irreducible quadratic factor $x^2+x+1$. The difference is that when $\alpha^{p-1}$ then $\alpha$ actually lies in $\Bbb{Z}_p$, and it is equal to its conjugate $\alpha^p$ (and Galois theory tells that the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ has degree one instead of being quadratic).

Comment: Basically, if $3\mid p-1$  and $g$ is a primitive root modulo $p$, then $g^{(p-1)/3}$ and $g^{2(p-1)/3}$ are roots of unity of order three, so zeros of $x^2+x+1$. And they belong to $\Bbb{Z}_p$!

Comment: Thank you very much @JyrkiLahtonen this is very useful. If I go through it in the other direction, then if $q|p+1$, then order of $\alpha$ as a root of unity should be a factor of $p+1$. Hence, taking $\alpha^{p+1}$ will give $\alpha^{p+1}=1$. Therefore product of $\alpha$ and $\alpha^p$ is equal to 1, and so the constant term in the quadratic equation is 1. $x^2-(\alpha+\alpha^p)x+\alpha \alpha^p$.

Comment: right? And for the case of $q|p-1$, can there be no quadratic factor at all...?

Comment: I have seen the matrix $(0 -1;1 -1)$ being taken as the rational canonical form to represent a linear transformation $T: (\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p) \rightarrow (\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p)$, where $T$ was used to represent a linear transformation in the Automorphism group of $(\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p)$ in semidirect product $(\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p) \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_3$. Then in this case the matrix representation is correct for both $3|p+1, 3|p-1$. That's why I require to figure it out...Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: If $q\mid p-1$ then $x^q-1$ splits into linear factors. Again, if $g$ is a primitive root modulo $p$, the powers $g^{j(p-1)/q}$, $j=0,1,\ldots,q-1$, are distinct zeros of $x^q-1$. This is a consequence of the fact that the multiplicative group of a finite field is always cyclic.

Comment: The matrix $$A=\pmatrix{0&-1\cr 1&-1\cr}$$ always gives that kind of a semidirect product (as it is the companion matrix of $x^2+x+1$). It has order $3$ for all $p$ (in characteristic zero also). A difference is that if $p\equiv1\pmod3$ then $A$ is diagonalizable over the prime field $\Bbb{Z}_p$, but if $p\equiv-1\pmod3$ then the eigenvalues belong to the extension field $\Bbb{F}_{p^2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. For example, $x^7 - 1 = (x-1)(x^6+x^5+ x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)$ modulo $19$ as a product of irreducible factors. It is easy to see that $x-1$ is always a factor, but from that point on I think more specific conditions may be required on $p$ and $q$ ($q<p$ seems arbitrary in this respect) for this breakup to occur.

Note : Showing explicitly that the sixth degree polynomial is irreducible requires Galois theory.

We will use the demonstration in the comments for this purpose. We wish to show that $$
x^6+x^5+ x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1
$$

is irreducible modulo $19$. Note that a root of this polynomial can be found in a finite field extension of $\mathbb F_{19}$, which will be of the form $\mathbb F_{19^m}$ for some $m$.

However, any root of this polynomial will also satisfy $x^7 = 1$, therefore we are ask : for which $m$ is there a non-unit $x$ such that $x^7 = 1$ as elements of $\mathbb F_{19^m}$?

If there is such an element $x$, then $7$ must divide $19^m-1$. Conversely, because $7$ is prime, $7$ dividing $19^m-1$ implies the converse by Cauchy's theorem. Therefore, the question now is : which $m$ are such that $7$ divides $19^m-1$?

One can easily check that the set of all such $m$ is of the form $n\mathbb N$ for $n$ being the possible smallest value of $m$. Combining Euler's theorem with a few simple tests, one sees that $m$ can be any multiple of $6$.

So, any root of $x^6+x^5+\ldots+1 = 0$ must then lie in an extension of degree at least $6$. However, because the degree of this polynomial is also at most $6$, it follows that the root lies in an extension of degree $6$, and therefore $x^6+x^5+\ldots+1$ is its minimal polynomial, hence irreducible over $\mathbb F_{19}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot @TeresaLisbon there is another additional condition: $q|p^2-1$. If there are quadratic factors as I have mentioned above I can write the rational canonical forms for possible conjugacy classes of matrices in a$GL_2(\mathbb{Z}_p)$.

Comment: @Thomas Thank you for the response, I will see if I can come up with something useful.

Comment: With the condition $q|p^2-1$, I have to get a $2\times 2$ matrix representing possible conjugacy classes. If $T$ is the matrix representing a linear transformation $T:(\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p) \rightarrow (\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p)$, there exist a basis ${u,T(u)}$, as well, so $T$ is of the form $(0 \, a; 1 \,b)$

Comment: (0, a representing the two elements of the first row of the matrtix. 1, b representing that of the second row). Also the minimal polynomial of $T$ always divides $x^q-1$, that's why I have taken as above. To have a $2 \times 2$ matrix representation, there should be quadratic factors. If so, then will the quadratic factors have the above mentioned form @TeresaLisbon ? If yes, the the matrix $T$ will have $a=-1$ by the rational canonical form, what do you think?

Comment: Sorry I couldn't mention the condition $q|p^2-1$.

Comment: @Thomas Just read what you've wrote, and I think you're right.

Comment: Thank you very much @TeresaLisbon can you please help me to prove it? That if there are going to be quadratic factors for such case, they are of the form $x^2+mx+1$ where $m \in \mathbb{Z}_p$

Comment: @Thomas I will give it a try.

Comment: Many many thanks @TeresaLisbon

Comment: Because $19\equiv5\pmod7$ and $5$ is a primitive root modulo $7$ it follows that $7\mid 19^m-1$ if and only if $m$ is divisible by $6=7-1$. Therefore the finite field $\Bbb{F}_{19^m}$ contains a seventh root of unity if and only if $m$ is divisible by six. It follows that the primitive polynomial of a seventh root of unity over $\Bbb{Z}_{19}$ must have degree six. You have found a degree six polynomial that has the said seventh root of unity as a zero. Therefore it is the minimal polynomial. Therefore it is irreducible.